# is there any problem with my file using flask?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, debugging, terminal

im trying to run my web app using flask. all the code is right bc i ran it a couple days ago. but i accidentally quit vscode and the terminal i was using doesnt work the same. it detects im using flask bc it gaves me the correct version of it but it doesnt let me run my app anymore and im really new at this.

[image]

Comment: Do not provide text as image. Provide the code as text and the errors as text.

Comment: The error you get when trying to start flask app already says what you need to do...

Comment: How do you execute the code? Do you want to read [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask)?

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `flask --app FileName run`, replacing `FileName` with your filename.
See [this page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/cli/#) for more information.

In the future, please provide code and errors in text, it makes it easier for people to reproduce the error.

Comment: why do yall care so much about the images??? if i want to show a terminal error which is knida big, how is an image supposed to be harder to read???

Comment: @Erick Pruneda
Sometimes the code is needed to reproduce the error and try to identify a solution: this can be very difficult if the code has been provided as an image. See this post for more information: [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)